# How to find max salary in each department,,

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to find max salary in each department?

```
let emp =[
    {
        'name':"A",
        'sal':86879,
        'dept':1
    },
    {
        'name':"B",
        'sal':3453674,
        'dept':2
    },
    {
        'name':"C",
        'sal':568867,
        'dept':3
    },
    {
        'name':"D",
        'sal':34661,
        'dept':1
    },
    {
        'name':"E",
        'sal':896556,
        'dept':2
    },
    {
        'name':"F",
        'sal':67678,
        'dept':3
    },
    {
        'name':"G",
        'sal':45654,
        'dept':4
    },{
        'name':"H",
        'sal':35677,
        'dept':4
    }
];
```

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: How to resolve this?

Comment: Make an object. Loop over array. Set key to the department. If does not exist add salary. If it does exist, check if salary is larger. If it is set it. Perfect example for `reduce()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look through each entry in the array, and check for the highest in each department by storing them in a separate object like this

```
const maxSal = {};
emp.forEach(e=>{
    if (!maxSal[e.dept] || maxSal[e.dept] < e.sal){
        maxSal[e.dept] = e.sal;
    }
});
```

maxSal is an object with the keys of the department, the value is the highest salary

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the array by taking `dept` and `val` and collect the max values in an object.

```js
const
    data = [{ name: "A", sal: 86879, dept: 1 }, { name: "B", sal: 3453674, dept: 2 }, { name: "C", sal: 568867, dept: 3 }, { name: "D", sal: 34661, dept: 1 }, { name: "E", sal: 896556, dept: 2 }, { name: "F", sal: 67678, dept: 3 }, { name: "G", sal: 45654, dept: 4 }, { name: "H", sal: 35677, dept: 4 }],
    result = data.reduce(
        (r, { dept, sal }) => (r[dept] = Math.max(r[dept] ?? -Number.MAX_VALUE, sal), r ),
        {}
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go `findHighestSallary` function will return the highest salary just pass the department no. as an argument.

```
let emp =[
    {
        'name':"A",
        'sal':86879,
        'dept':1
    },
    {
        'name':"B",
        'sal':3453674,
        'dept':2
    },
    {
        'name':"C",
        'sal':568867,
        'dept':3
    },
    {
        'name':"D",
        'sal':34661,
        'dept':1
    },
    {
        'name':"E",
        'sal':896556,
        'dept':2
    },
    {
        'name':"F",
        'sal':67678,
        'dept':3
    },
    {
        'name':"G",
        'sal':45654,
        'dept':4
    },{
        'name':"H",
        'sal':35677,
        'dept':4
    }
];


function findHighestSallary(dept) {
    let myarray = [];
    
    emp.map((x) => {
        if(x.dept === dept){
            myarray.push(x);
        }
    })
    
    myarray.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.sal - a.sal;
    });
    
    return myarray[0].sal;
}

console.log(findHighestSallary(1));
```